# symfony 3.4 : forms : Use Data Transformers

Tags: forms, symfony

trying to use data transformer, I have an error when loadding my html form

In my formType class

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class PmpType extends AbstractType
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
}
```

in my app\config\services.yml

```
services:
# default configuration for services in *this* file
 _defaults:
    # automatically injects dependencies in your services
    autowire: true
    # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    autoconfigure: true
    # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
    # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
    public: true
```

but I received this error

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function myApp\Bundle\Form\PmpType::__construct(), 0 passed in \vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php on line 92 and exactly 1 expected
```

What do I miss

Thx for hepl

Answer (score 1):

OK 
I don't understand why but I have toset the service for my class : 
in service.yml, I add

```
    seims_pmp.pmptype:
      class: SEISM\PmpIG56Bundle\Form\PmpType
      arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
      tags: [form.type]
```

and now it's working